# Jq: Create new empty object with existing property as its key

Tags: json, jq

If I have a json file as follows:

```
{
 config: {
   name: "test1"
   }
}
```

How would I use `jq` to create an empty object named after "test1" in a new file? 
i.e.

```
test1: {
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that there's only 1 line in `config.name` file that says "test1" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I suggest you make original file a proper JSON by adding quotes to keys:

```
{
  "config": {
      "name": "test1"
  }
}
```

Now you can do it like this:

```
jq '{(.config.name):{}}' config.name
```

Output:

```
{
  "test1": {}
}
```

Comment: You misunderstand, config.name is the property within the json file that I want the object to be named after. I've updated the OP.